# How do you send packets via PacketConn.WriteTo?

Tags: go, network-programming

I want to set up a PacketConn interface and then send arbitrary UDP messages, to a specified address that a user inputs. Here's my code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

//Make a type that implemets https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Addr
type remoteAddress struct {
    myAddress string
}

func (r remoteAddress) Network() string {
    return "udp"
}

func (r remoteAddress) String() string {
    return r.myAddress
}

func writePeer(pc net.PacketConn, addr net.Addr){
    for{
        if _, err := pc.WriteTo([]byte("hi"), addr); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second/3)
    }
}

func main(){
    pc, err := net.ListenPacket("udp", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var userInput remoteAddress
    userInput.myAddress = "99.84.243.36:80"

    go writePeer(pc, userInput)

    select{}

}
```

When the program runs, I get the error:
`panic: write udp [::]:57057->99.84.243.36:80: invalid argument`
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do not implement your own `net.Addr` type. Use [`net.UDPAddr`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#UDPAddr).

Comment: @TimCooper I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @TimCooper That works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's working code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)



func writePeer(pc net.PacketConn, addr net.Addr){
    for{
        if _, err := pc.WriteTo([]byte("hi"), addr); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second/3)
    }
}

func main(){
    pc, err := net.ListenPacket("udp", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    userInput, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "99.84.243.36:80")

    go writePeer(pc, userInput)

    select{}

}
```

Comment: net.ResolveUDPAddr() is what I was looking for